# Android account manager getPassword returns Null

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am investigating ways in which Android account manager may return empty password for an account. I have tried following things:

1. Launch an app which creates say XYZ account. Then explicitly go in Settings->XYZ and delete that account.

   - In my app I have checks to make sure whenever account is NULL, create a new one and then only call getPassword. So I am not able to repro empty password scenario
2. Use my app in "Owner mode" and in restricted mode give access to my app. What will happen? will restricted user be able to use XYZ account or getPassword will return Null?

Comment: Why exactly would you want the AccountManager to return a null password? Are you debugging an actual issue? If so, it might be helpful to include some more info, like: Does it occur on specific devices/Android versions only?

Comment: I am debugging an actual issue. End users are seeing it but apart from an exception saying "password is null" we are not getting other information. That is why trying to find in what all scenarios Account manager password could get corrupted.

It occurs mostly on 5.0 and 5.0.1 android devices of various make.

Comment: The documentation of [getPassword](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getPassword%28android.accounts.Account%29) says it will return `null` if the password is actually set to `null` or the account doesn't exist. We've not observed other reasons for `null` passwords in our apps. There are broken Android version that delete accounts of paid apps during an app update though.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please mention which all Android Versions delete accounts on app update? App upgrade is a valid scenario for us.

Comment: We've seen this in Android 4.4.2, see [issue 66905](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66905). Android 5.x seems to be affected too. We don't know yet about Android 6.